# Can anyone tell me the problem of this code (it is to write even and odd numbers in separate files.)?

Tags: c, file, integer

I want to print even and odd in separate file only up to 50.Given below is the program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp1,*fp2,*fp3;
    int i,n;
    fp1=fopen("data","w");
    for(i=1;i<=50;i++)
       fprintf(fp1,"%d",i);
    fclose(fp1);
    fp1=fopen("data","r");
    fp2=fopen("even","w");
    fp3=fopen("odd","w");
    while(!feof(fp1))
    {
        fscanf(fp1,"%d",&n);
        if(n%2==0)
          fprintf(fp2,"%d",n);
        else
          fprintf(fp3,"%d",n);
    }   
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);
    fp1=fopen("data","r");
    fp2=fopen("even","r");
    fp3=fopen("odd","r");
    while(!feof(fp1))
    {
        fscanf(fp1,"%d",&n);
        printf("%d",n);
    }
    puts("\n Even file");
    puts("_________________");
    while(!feof(fp2))
    {
        fscanf(fp2,"%d",&n);
        printf("%d",n);
    }
    puts("\n Odd file");
    puts("_________________");
    while(!feof(fp3))
    {
        fscanf(fp3,"%d",&n);
        printf("%d",n);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);
    getch();
}
```

But i get the output
as shown below

```
-856714730
 Even file
_________________
-856714730
 Odd file
_________________
-856714730
```

Do anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Well, obviously you have written the numbers smashed together into a single long number like 13579..., which `scanf` can't read properly. Print a space or a newline after each number with `"%d "` or `"%d\n"`. (You can look into the files with an editor to see what got written. Also, please check all the I/O commands for errors.)

Comment: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong) You can use the return value from `fscanf` to control the loop: `while(fscanf(fp2, "%d", &n) == 1)`

Comment: Your code is crying out for a function such as `void read_file(const char *tag, const char *filename) { … }` which uses the tag in the information message about what's being read and opens, reads and closes the file.  You'd then call it three time: `read_file("Data", "data"); read_file("Even", "even"); read_file("Odd", "odd");`.  This is basic software engineering — DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).